# how to save a php data that has been encoded into a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, jquery-select2

I have a data "`echo json_encode ($ data ['airlines']);`" I want to save the data to a variable in javascript

In javascript

```
const input = {json_encode ($ data ['airlines']);}
```

In php

```
echo json_encode($data['airlines']);
```

Comment: Unclear whether you want to get the data via Ajax or if you’re wanting to hard code it will not a JavaScript object when printing out the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php

```
$airlines = $data['airlines'];
```

In java script you can accessed with {!! $airlines!!}

```
const input = '{!! json_encode ($airlines) !!}';
//Parse the data with JSON.parse(), and the data becomes a JavaScript object.
 var obj = JSON.parse(input);
 console.log(obj);
```